# SQL parameter in NOT LIKE dynamic sql

Tags: sql, dynamic-sql, sql-like

Dynamic SQL with a NOT LIKE is not accepting the parameter passed in for some reason. It works if I don't pass in the parameter to the dynamic call and rather builds the string with the word in it

For some reason this call does not work for the @noteText parameter in the NOT LIKE of the delete and ends up deleting everything from the temp table.
I need the below to work for when words with apostrophes are passed in as building it dynamically throws in error for an invalid string quotation.

```
declare @bsearchbody bit=1
declare @bsearchtitle bit =0
declare @notetext varchar(10)='that''s'

create table #matched( id int,note varchar(800),title varchar(800))
INSERT INTO #matched
select 1,'this is just a test. that''s fun.','test1'
UNION ALL
SELECT 2,' note on the ID','the is just a title'
UNION ALL
SELECT 3,'I watched basketball last night','basketball type'

declare @vchsql nvarchar(1000)=N'
DELETE from #matched
WHERE 1=1 AND (' + CASE WHEN @bSearchBody=1 THEN 'ISNULL(note,'''')  NOT LIKE ''%@noteText%''' ELSE '' END +
                    CASE WHEN @bSearchBody=1 AND @bSearchTitle=1 THEN ' AND ' ELSE  '' END +
                    CASE WHEN @bSearchTitle=1 THEN 'ISNULL(title,'''')  NOT LIKE 

    ''%@noteText%''' ELSE '' END + 
                    ')'

                    print @vchsql
    exec sp_executesql @vchsql,N'@notetext varchar(10)',@notetext
```

The script works when the parameter @notetext and the dynamic sql looks like this (when the word does not have an apostrophe in it).

```
declare @bsearchbody bit=1
declare @bsearchtitle bit =0
declare @notetext varchar(10)='test'

create table #matched( id int,note varchar(800),title varchar(800))
INSERT INTO #matched
select 1,'this is just a test.','test1'
UNION ALL
SELECT 2,' note on the ID','the is just a title'
UNION ALL
SELECT 3,'I watched basketball last night','basketball type'

declare @vchsql nvarchar(1000)=N'
DELETE from #matched
WHERE 1=1 AND (' + CASE WHEN @bSearchBody=1 THEN 'ISNULL(note,'''')  NOT LIKE ''%'+ @noteText+ '%''' ELSE '' END +
                    CASE WHEN @bSearchBody=1 AND @bSearchTitle=1 THEN ' AND ' ELSE  '' END +
                    CASE WHEN @bSearchTitle=1 THEN 'ISNULL(title,'''')  NOT LIKE ''%@noteText%''' ELSE '' END + 
                ')'

                print @vchsql
exec sp_executesql @vchsql,N'@notetext varchar(10)',@notetext
```

Comment: Don't forget that a text containing reserved characters of `LIKE`(e.g. `[]%_`) may not behave as expected when passed into @noteText.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that SQL interprets the value as a string rather than a parameter.  So, construct the pattern.  Instead of:

```
'ISNULL(title, '''')  NOT LIKE ''%@noteText%'''
```

use:

```
'COALESCE(title, '''')  NOT LIKE ''%'' + @noteText + ''%'''
```

Comment: You beat me to it - but why replace ISNULL with COALESCE? I don't see a benefit here.

Comment: @Lucero . .  Personal preference.  I prefer the ANSI functions when they are essentially equivalent.